# One To One eloquent Relationship

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I write in my model a relationships between  two models

```
public function cat()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Cat');
    }
```

and use it in my Controller

```
Model1::with('cat')->get();
```

I have problem. this relationship fetch all record from table one. I want if record in first table has not record in second table It does not fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the method Has(); appears to be like inner join So in the controller i do:

```
Model1::has('cat')->with('cat')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the data from cat table you should do this :

```
 $model1 = Model1::findOrFail($id);

 $model1->cat;
```